# should I use modules in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, module

I am learning **angular4**. I read somewhere that some version of angular2 introduced modules using `@NgModule`.

Suppose I am creating an application for accounting. So, there will be different functionalities like groups, ledgers etc. So, based on functionality I can divide it in modules like GroupsModule, LedgersModule etc. So, suppose first I create my `GroupsModule` which will look like :

```
GroupsModule
  |--Classes
       |--Group.ts
  |--Components
       |--Group-list
            |--Group-list.component.ts
            |--Group-list.component.html
            |--Group-list.component.css
       |--Group-create
            |--Group-create.component.ts
            |--Group-create.component.html
            |--Group-create.component.css
  |--Services
       |--Group.service.ts
  |--Group.Module.ts
```

Now If I create Ledger module then I will have to refactor GroupsModule and move some of its files to SharedModule because my LedgersModule will need to access some parts of GroupsModule, so now my GroupsModule will look like:

```
GroupsModule
  |--Components
       |--Group-list
            |--Group-list.component.ts
            |--Group-list.component.html
            |--Group-list.component.css
       |--Group-create
            |--Group-create.component.ts
            |--Group-create.component.html
            |--Group-create.component.css
  |--Group.Module.ts
```

LedgersModule will look like:

```
LedgersModule
  |--Classes
       |--Ledger.ts
  |--Components
       |--Ledger-list
            |--Ledger-list.component.ts
            |--Ledger-list.component.html
            |--Ledger-list.component.css
       |--Group-create
            |--Ledger-create.component.ts
            |--Ledger-create.component.html
            |--Ledger-create.component.css
  |--Services
       |--Ledger.service.ts
  |--Ledger.Module.ts
```

SharedModule will look like this:

```
SharedModule
  |--Classes
       |--Group.ts
  |--Services
       |--Group.service.ts
  |--Shared.Module.ts
```

In this approach I have two problems:

**Problem1:**

I have to keep refactoring my completed modules, so that other modules can use them.

**Problem:2**

I have separated my code in modules, so that I can keep my code private.

For example, If I create another module called `SomeOtherModule` which will need to use some parts of `LedgersModule`. So, now I have to refactor `LedgersModule` and move some of its files in `SharedModule`. Now `SomeOtherModule` will reference `SharedModule` and it will get access to Ledger files that it needs. But now `SomeOtherModule` can also use **Group.service.ts** as it is referencing `SharedModule`. So, my code is not private now. I don't want `SomeOtherModule` to have  access to my (originally) `GroupModule` files from `SharedModule`.

In my application all or most of the Modules are dependent on other modules. But those modules should only be allowed to have access to the facilities they need, just not more than that.

Then why should I use modules? I can do the same thing without modules.

Can you suggest me should I use modules in such situation? Or would it be better to use only AppModule and do everything there?

Comment: Not clear about your consideration without using modules. Do you mean using original JavaScript module instead of angular modules?